# How to pass/get an object in custom dojo event explicitly (as argument)

Tags: dojo

I have two nested dojo widgets. Child widget emits custom event on click, which is handled by parent.

Child widget:

```
elementClick: function (e) {
    this.onSelected(this.el)
},

onSelected: function(el) {
   //extension point
},
```

Parent widget:

```
const elementSelected = function () {
    console.log(this) 
    /*
    here `this` references just to what I need,
    but `this` in contex of parent widget looks confusing
    */
}

const bingSelectedHandler = function (el) {
    el.on('selected', elementSelected)
}
```

I'd like to get rid of confusing `this` keyword in event handler in parent widget. Is there any way to do it to make it work in such way, for example:

```
const elementSelected = function (element) {
    console.log(element) //use argument instead of `this` keyword

}
```

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: the code is not clear, can you show how the child widget is instantiated and used by the parent, also where the parent is instantiated and used, and how the events are triggered

Comment: Thank you, I've managed to find a solution already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is very easy and obvious, and I don't know why it didn't work for me when i tried it first time.

In child element we just pass current widget as an argument in function which is 'extension point', as it called in dojo:

```
return declare('TreeElement', [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
    <... other widget's methods and properties ...>

        elementClick: function(e) {
            if (e.target.classList.contains('checkbox')) {
                return false
            }

            //Here, pass 'this' as an argument 
            this.onFocused(this)

        },
        onFocused: function() {}
    })
```